# How to prevent ef index in base class gets inherited in derived class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I have these 2 classes

```
public class BaseClass
{
  [Key] 
  [Column(Order=1)]
  public int id1 { get; set;}
  [Key] 
  [Column(Order=2)]
  [Index("UQ_MyIndex", 1, IsUnique = true)] 
  public int id2 { get; set; }
  [Index("UQ_MyIndex", 2, IsUnique = true)] 
  public string code {get; set;} 
}

public class ChildClass : BaseClass
{
  public int OtherProperty { get; set;}
}
```

Child class is inherited using Table per Type (TPT). The problem is that when i add migration, i get 2 index of "IX_MyIndex" in baseclass and childclass. And worse, because "code" does not exists in ChildClass db table, the child class index only has the "id2". I can delete this in the migration file, but is there any other solution to prevent index gets inherited?